What flag do I need to set in an epub file so that Apple Books will add "excerpt from" and credit information to every copy/paste?
In some epubs I've purchased, when I open these in Apple Books, attempts to copy-paste a quote will add 4 or 5 lines to the pasted text including "Excerpt from" and this some minimal citation. Since this is such a useful feature to people who wanted to copy a name out of the book (perhaps with accent marks that are difficult to type), it would be great if I could add it to my own hand-crafted books as well. I'm assuming there is some flag to set in the opf file, but I am ignorant of the exact mechanism or how it works. Perhaps there is a different way to do this?
Any help would be appreciated.
